# Problem in redirecting to a page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a web application.

I've wrriten a jsp, servlet and a bean. On sucessful insertion of records into database I want to redirediect to a new page but `response.sendredirect()` reports an error.

**The error**

The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:126)
    allotmant.seatAllot.processRequest(seatAllot.java:104)
    allotmant.seatAllot.doGet(seatAllot.java:134)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
```

**Note:** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.

What could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot send a redirect after commiting the headers of the response. When you redirect the header must contain the redirect action. But if you already sent some body content the headers are committed.

So maybe you are sending body content (or mannually commiting the headers) before the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're:

1. Performing the redirect early enough in the page. If it's too late in the page then the response headers will have already been committed to the stream. It only buffers so many bytes before beginning to send to the client, typically 8k.
2. Immediately stop processing the rest of the page once you do the `sendRedirect()`. For the same reason as #1 if you let the rest of the page render it can fill up the response buffer. Call `return` right after your `sendRedirect()` to end your servlet, JSP or the like.